# How to properly implement -> and (*). so that they behave like -> and (*). in an iterator

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, dereference

I'd like to implement the * and -> operators for the iterator of a custom-made container. My code doesn't compile. Below a "Minimal Non-working example", which shows how it works with std::map but not in my code.

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

struct thing {
  float f[1];
  typedef std::pair<int,float> key_data;

  struct iterator {
    int pos;
    const float *f;
    key_data operator*() const { return key_data(pos,f[pos]); }
    key_data *operator->() const { return &key_data(pos,f[pos]); }
  };

  iterator begin() const { return {.f = f, .pos = 0}; }
};

template<typename T> void test(T iter) {
  (*iter).second = 1.0; std::cout << (*iter).second;

  iter->second = 2.0; std::cout << iter->second;
}

int main() {
  std::map<int,float> fmap; fmap[0] = 0.0;
  test(fmap.begin());
  std::cout << fmap[0];

  thing f;
  test(f.begin());
  std::cout << f.f[0];
}
```

I would like this to compile :), and print `122122`. The error messages on compilation are:

```
access.cc:13:43: error: taking the address of a temporary object of type 'key_data'
      (aka 'pair<int, float>') [-Waddress-of-temporary]
    key_data *operator->() const { return &key_data(pos,f[pos]); }

access.cc:20:18: error: expression is not assignable
  (*iter).second = 1.0; std::cout << (*iter).second;
```

For the first: fair enough, std::pair<> creates a temporary which can't be returned by reference; but how does the Standard library do it to allow the usual -> syntax?

For the second: probably again I'm trying to assign into a temporary, but I can't guess what the right syntax is.

Comment: Well it's difficult because the objects you want the iterator to return don't exist in the container you are iterating over. That's not a problem the STL has in general.

Comment: Ah, so you mean that it works in STL because internally the entries are already pairs? Bummer...

Comment: You might be able to get something to work by creating an [input iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator) which stores the iterator value in the iterator itself. The point about an input iterator is that incrementing it invalidates all previous values (because the iterator holds the value it will get overwritten when the iterator is incremented).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simpler is to have directly correct type in iterator:

```
struct thing {
  float f[1];
  using key_data = std::pair<int,float&>;

  struct iterator {
    key_data data;
    const key_data& operator*() { return data; }
    key_data *operator->() { return &data; }
  };

  iterator begin() { return {{0, f[0] }}; }
};
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/kbw0Ze)

Another solution is to have wrapper, something like:

```
struct pair_wrapper
{
    int &first;
    float& second;

    pair_wrapper* operator->() { return this; }
};

struct thing {
  float f[1];
  typedef std::pair<int,float> key_data;

  struct iterator {
    int pos;
    float *f;
    pair_wrapper operator*() { return pair_wrapper{pos,f[pos]}; }
    pair_wrapper operator->() { return pair_wrapper{pos,f[pos]}; }
  };

  iterator begin() { return {0, f}; }
};
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/qj1wFs)

It uses the "magic" chaining of `operator->`.